# How do I change only one element of a Seq?

Tags: scala, sequence, higher-order-functions, seq

I have an immutable Seq. I need to create a new Seq from it, with only one element changed, whose index is given to me. How can I do it ? (I think since the sequence is immutable I will need to use some function and create a new output sequence, but I do not know how to check index for conditional update in the "map" function.) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If the element has to be transformed with some function `f` then

```
val idx = 2 // given index to transform

mySeq.iterator.zipWithIndex.map { 
  case (e, `idx`) => f(e)
  case (e, _) => e
}.toSeq
```

If it just needs to be replaced with another given element then

```
mySeq.updated(idx, newElement)
```

If collection will be frequently updated then consider `Vector` instead because `List` which is the default implementation of `Seq` is not [optimised](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/performance-characteristics.html) for updates.

Comment: You can still use `updated` to avoid the whole `map` : `mySeq.updated(idx, f(mySeq(idx)))`, specially if the underlying collection has fast access by index.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ah that is much nicer solution than mapping!

Comment: Yeah, but again, it only makes sense if the underlying collection is something like a **Vector**, otherwise the cost of the access + the cost of the `updated` will be worse than the `map` in the **Iterator**. This is the kind of reasons why I do not like **Seq** in general.